# SQlite3 not inserting a row

Tags: python, sqlite, oop

I am creating a login and sign-up program to be exact, and I am currently having a little trouble in inserting a row by the given value which is the *Username* and *Password* input.

I have two python files one is the *Main.py* and the second one is *functions.py* which is obviously the functions and classes of my program.

Pycharm doesn't throw an Error so I wanna ask what is wrong with my code? Why does it not inserting a row?

*Main.py*

```
    while 1:
        s = SignUp 
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")

        s(username, password)

        print("Done!")
        break
```

*functions.py*

```
c = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
class SignUp:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def signu(self):
        c.execute(f'''INSERT INTO info (username, password) VALUES ('{self.username}', '{self.password}'); ''')
        c.commit()
```

and this is the class that will accept the given *username* and *password* value from main.py

this is where the table got created

```
c = sqlite3.connect('registration.db')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (username     TEXT    NOT NULL, password      TEXT    NOT NULL);''')
```

Comment: You never call `signu()`

Comment: Don't substitute variables directly into the SQL string. Use placeholders in the query, and the parameters argument to `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: What's the purpose of a `while` loop that always breaks?

Comment: i did, it's in s variable

Comment: i actually added a conditional statement inside the while loop which will check whether the given username is already in the table and if it is then it will call out continue syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQLite with python, you need to create a cursor.

Table Creation:

```py
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('registration.db')

c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL)')

conn.commit()
c.close()
```

`main.py`:

```py
username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")

user1 = SignUp(username, password)
user1.signu()

print("Done!")
```

`function.py`:

```py
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('registration.db')
c=conn.cursor()

class SignUp:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def signu(self):
        c.execute(f'INSERT INTO info (username, password) VALUES ("self.username}", "{self.password}")')
        conn.commit()

c.close()
```

Comment: please click the checkmark if this is the answer

Comment: thanks, it works. I just forgot to create a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling the method that performs the `INSERT` query.

And you need to create a cursor to execute the query.

```
c = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
class SignUp:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def signu(self):
        cur = c.cursor()
        cur.execute(f'''INSERT INTO info (username, password) VALUES (?, ?); ''', (self.username, self.password))
        c.commit()

username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")

s = Signup(username, password)
s.signu()

print("Done!")
```

Comment: the problem is not him forgetting to call the method (he calls it in main.py). The problem is that he doesn't create a cursor. Also don't create a cursor in signu (if signu is called multiple time, multiple cursors will be created)

Comment: Where does he call it in `main.py`? I just see `s(username, password)`

Comment: good point :), still will be good to talk about the cursor (not just add the line)